# R : Export language error

Tags: r, csv

I would like to export data to csv but my data language is not English. In R console they showed me correctly but when I exported to csv they showed in error (ex. £à¸¸à¸à¸•à¸¥à¸²à¸”à¸«à¸™à¸±à¸à¸¡à¸²à¸ #à¸£à) How can I fix this problem ?

Here is a code.

write.csv(tweetsDF, "/Users/mac/Documents/tweets.csv",fileEncoding = "UTF-8")

Thanks.

Comment: What language are you using? What operating system do you use?

Comment: I using in Thai language and my os is Macintosh.

Comment: Strange, I copied text copied from wikipedia into R to create a dataframe and write a csv file. Here your command worked perfectly (also on Mac OS). Where from and in what format do you get your original data?

Comment: I import data from twitter  : tweetdata <-searchTwitter("xxx",n=1000,lang="th") , the data showed me in Thai but when I export to csv they showed in error. What should I do ?